# Split the line into next line after a matching pattern

Tags: text-processing, sed, text-formatting

In the input file shown below, I am trying to find the string `job_type` and move the it to the next line if it matches job_type.

I tried this, but it is not working:

```
sed "s/[A-Z][a-z]*job_type:/\njob_type:/g"
```

Input:

```
    insert_job: VAU_vaultnotification_ertgvfg_job job_type: xxx 
    insert_job: VAU_vaultnotification_ertgvfg_frd job_type: yyy 
    insert_job: VAU_vaultnotification_ertgvfg_erb job_type: SXC 
     job_type: CMD
    insert_job: VAU_vaultnotification_ertgvfg_frd job_type: YUI
```

Expected output:

```
insert_job: VAU_vaultnotification_ertgvfg_job 
job_type: xxx 
insert_job: VAU_vaultnotification_ertgvfg_frd 
job_type: yyy 
insert_job: VAU_vaultnotification_ertgvfg_erb 
job_type: SXC 
 job_type: CMD
insert_job: VAU_vaultnotification_ertgvfg_frd 
job_type: YUI
```

Comment: I tried to clarify, but I don't understand what you mean by "and job_type trailed with alphabets and space". Should `abcdjob_type` be a match? Can you include some cases that should _not_ be changed? How does the `sed` command fail? Does it not run? Does it run but do the wrong thing? Please ***edit*** your question and clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements are not clear to me, but maybe you want:

```
sed 's/\([[:upper:]][[:alpha:]_]*\)[[:space:]]\{1,\}\(job_type:\)/\1\
\2/g'
```

Or:

```
perl -Mopen=locale -pe 's/\b\p{Lu}\w*\K\s+(job_type:)/\n$1/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something similar to this, using GNU `sed`:

```
sed '/insert_job/s/job_type/\njob_type/'
```

The first part `/insert_job/` matches that on a line before doing the substitution.  If "insert_job" (or whatever regex you prefer) is not found, it won't do the the substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed '/ \+\(insert_job.*\)\(job_type:.*\)/s//\1\n\2/' input_file
insert_job: VAU_vaultnotification_ertgvfg_job
job_type: xxx
insert_job: VAU_vaultnotification_ertgvfg_frd
job_type: yyy
insert_job: VAU_vaultnotification_ertgvfg_erb
job_type: SXC
     job_type: CMD
insert_job: VAU_vaultnotification_ertgvfg_frd
job_type: YUI
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

Assuming lines-to-be-modified all contain at least 4 whitespace-separated "columns" (lines with fewer than 4 "columns" are returned unmodified):

```perl
raku -ne 'my @a = .words; @a.elems >= 4 ?? put @a[0..1], "\n", @a[2..*] !! put @a;'
```

Above assumes no string pattern in the input, only the appropriate number of whitespace-separated `words` (i.e. columns). For matching lines, the first 2 columns are returned, then a newline, then the remaining columns (the OP provides Sample Input wherein the string `job_type` begins the 3rd column).

However, if you want to use a regex and search for string patterns, Raku has your back (using the `subst` operator). Below, Raku searches for 8 regex atoms between `/ ^ ... $ /`, between the `^` start-of-string and `$` end-of-string zero-width assertions (anchors). Once matched, Raku's `<(` capture marker is used to drop everything before `job_type` from the match. Then in the `subst` replacement half, a `\n` newline is `~` concatenated to the `$/` match-variable and returned.

```perl
raku -ne '.subst(/^ insert_job\: \s .+? \s <(job_type\: \s \w* \s*? $/, {"\n"~$/} ).put;'
```

Sample Input:

```
insert_job: VAU_vaultnotification_ertgvfg_job job_type: xxx 
insert_job: VAU_vaultnotification_ertgvfg_frd job_type: yyy 
insert_job: VAU_vaultnotification_ertgvfg_erb job_type: SXC 
 job_type: CMD
insert_job: VAU_vaultnotification_ertgvfg_frd job_type: YUI
```

Sample Output (first code example, above):

```
insert_job: VAU_vaultnotification_ertgvfg_job
job_type: xxx
insert_job: VAU_vaultnotification_ertgvfg_frd
job_type: yyy
insert_job: VAU_vaultnotification_ertgvfg_erb
job_type: SXC
job_type: CMD
insert_job: VAU_vaultnotification_ertgvfg_frd
job_type: YUI
```

Note, the OP hasn't made clear if all output should be left-justified or not (zero leading-whitespace characters). The first answer above is left-justified, however it's easy to `trim` or even indent all lines that start with `job_type` in the output (for example, in the second answer using `{"\n "~$/}` in the replacement will indent).

https://raku.org